# To create a trigger in sql for my requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

The following is my tables

```
table1
=========
id          col1            col2
=====================================
1          firstrow          firstrow2
2          secrow            secrow2

table2
===========
id         orignalvalue          updatedvalue
===============================================
2           secrow2               Secondrow2
```

i need  a trigger when my table1 values are updated,a row to be created in the table2 with the id,originalvalue and the updatevalue in it...This is just like an LOG table.

Comment: How would you differentiate between an update to `col1` vs. an update to `col2` in your `table2`?

Comment: You did not actually ask a question. What problem are you having with creating the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically looking at an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to insert the `OLD` and `NEW` values into `table2` but without knowing which DB you're using, the syntax may differ or it might not even be possible.

Comment: Database Management System. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc